# Where did Stephen Wolfram get the idea of an intrinsic dimension of hypergraphs?

Tags: graph-theory, hypergraphs, neighbourhood

Stephen Wolfram provides an interesting description of dimension [here](https://www.wolframphysics.org/technical-introduction/limiting-behavior-and-emergent-geometry/the-notion-of-dimension/). There are only a few citations but he says

> The procedure we will follow is straightforward (cf. [1:p479][22]). For any point X in the graph define Vr(X) to be the number of points in the graph that can be reached by going at most graph distance r. This can be thought of as the volume of a ball of radius r in the graph centered at X.

That reference [22] is **[22] C. Druţu and M. Kapovich (2018), Geometric Group Theory, Colloquium.** in his references for that page.

This would suggest that I should look to page 479 of [22]. When I do, I see the end of a subsection on G-trees and the start of a section on **An existence theorem for harmonic functions**. The reference is not obvious.

Where did this notion of scale dimension come from?

Comment: I think you've misread this: it's telling you to look at p.479 of reference [1], not p.479 of reference [22].

Comment: @MatthewTowers I think you are right. [Page 479](https://www.wolframscience.com/nks/p479--space-as-a-network/) seems to be in a section about modelling space as a network model, and dimension is mentioned there.